# Parsing RSS feeds

Tags: java, parsing, rss

I am building rss reader that can read RSS feeds. Are there any helpful libraries in java to not reinvent the wheel like parsing the xml or organizing the feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How about [Rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/)?  Along with a [how-to article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2007/jw-11-rome.html).
- There's also [YARFRAW](http://yarfraw.sourceforge.net/), Yet Another RSS Feed Reader and Writer.
- Oh, and there's [GoogleReaderAPI](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI).

There's more if you google around a bit.  The magic search term for me was "java rss reader api"

I personally have used Rome in a project and it has a pretty decent API for generating RSS feeds.  I haven't used it to consume them though.

Comment: http://java.net/projects/rome/ links to http://rometools.org/, which is an expired domain. Is Rome still being maintained?

Comment: Honestly I don't know.  I've been working .net now for a while.  Open source projects can change a lot in a couple years.

Comment: It seems to still be active, but on https://rometools.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa, it would be good for future reference to perahps update the link. cheers